# Geo. Nodes: Possible to output objects in hierarchy?

Tags: unity, geometry-nodes

I've used geometry nodes to create a procedural tree, and am trying to use the same parameters I'm using for the branches to output points (the little cubes in the image, as placeholders) along the top of each branch that I'll use once I bring the model into Unity. Specifically, I'll have a script that will collect the points and use them for character navigation (I don't need the cubes, just objects in a hierarchy at the right points).

I can't figure out how to get geometry nodes to turn these into individual objects/meshes within a hierarchy so that I can handle them separately. Is there a way to do this? It seems I can only output one solid mesh.

Sharing the parameters between the branches and these points is important so I can generate lots of different types and geometries of trees procedurally without having to manually set the points or duplicate the inputs used to generate the branches and points; also, I can obviously turn off the tree geometry and just output the points into my scene separately, but they still output as one mesh, not individual ones, so it doesn't really help.

I expect to have a similar problem with leaves on my trees, as my compute shaders for drawing and billboarding them would need separate meshes that I'd like to be able to set up in blender but then handle drawing separately in Unity.

Any help would be very appreciated!

[image: Tree with points on branches]

Comment: maybe you could place a small cube object as a child of your GN mesh -ideally just a line with a vertex per cube-, then in Properties Panel > Object > Instancing > set it to vertices, and then Ctrl+A > Make Instances Real

Comment: Not sure how this keeps me from having to manually position the points? Might be missing something! But in case I didn't make it clear, the cubes are derived from the same curve parameters that create the branches (just offset up a bit and instanced to cubes instead of adding a circle radius to the curve like I do with the branches), so it's fairly automatic. Placing each manually along the top of the branch on many different tree models seems like a poor solution. Definitely open to different ways to do this, just surprised that the only output from GN *seems* to be a single compound mesh.

Comment: it's pretty trivial to convert to mesh and separate loose parts... anyway [this is what I meant](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9i6saqpd28nx1g/dupliverts.blend?dl=1), press Ctrl+A > Make Instances Real and then move to a collection... doesn't need to be a different object, could just have a switch or disable some part of node you use when instancing / exporting

Comment: Ahh you are correct, when set up like this (not how I'd set mine up), make instances real absolutely works. Thank you!

Comment: cool, just a workaround but it worked for you... to make it clear, have a minimal GN mesh where you can duplivert some object, then Ctrl+A and make those objects real, then M > new collection and done

Comment: @jack_was_taken It would be great of you to write a short answer to this and mark it as "Accepted Answer" so that this question shows up as solved. Thank you!